# Ionic Secure Storage get() at the start of the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a service that gets a token for validate an Auth status at the /src/main.ts:

```
if (TokenService.getAccessToken() !== undefined) {
...
}
```

token.service.ts

```
import storage from '@/plugins/storage'

const ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = "access_token";

const TokenService = {
    getAccessToken(){
        storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY).then(v => {
            return v
        })
    },
    async saveAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
        storage.set(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, accessToken);
    },
}

export { TokenService };
```

storage.ts:

```
import { Storage, Drivers } from '@ionic/storage'

const localStorage = new Storage()
localStorage.create()

const storage = {
    set: async(i: any, v: any) => {
        await localStorage.set(i, v)
    },
    get(i: any){
        return localStorage.get(i)
    },
    remove: async (i: any) => {
        await localStorage.remove(i);
    },
    clear: async () => {
        await localStorage.clear();
    }
}

export default storage
```

i only get **undefined** but when using console.log() inside the storage.ts i get the value but after the app started.

i also use this function to make a condition in /router/index.ts
when i was using localStorage i was getting the values well.

my dependencies:

```
    "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.4",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.6.0-dev.202102221703.5300dcc",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.6.0-dev.202102221703.5300dcc",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
```

What can i do?
thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

I'm spotting a problem in your *token.service.ts*, you are not returning nothing at: `getAccessToken`

```
// async since is returning a promise
async getAccessToken(){
    // Returning the promise.
    return storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY)
}
```

Using it from the outside will look like this:

```
// using await because we want the promise to be solved
if ((await TokenService.getAccessToken()) !== undefined) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It seems i cant use await in main.ts i get: ' Cannot use keyword await outside an async function '

Comment: Thats correct, await can only be use inside an async function.If you have no function, you could always use the normal promise approach `TokenService.getAccessToken().then(token=>{/*undefined check or any other code*/})`

Comment: Thanks. you know any way if its possible to get the value using only the getAccessToken() function without then() ?

Comment: Are you sure that storage.get returns a promise?? Reviewing the docs from Ionic doesn't seem to returns a promise and if thats the case then you can use it as a normal method without, async, await or then. But if it is returning a promise then you have to wait for the promise to be fulfilled